# assigning text to axis title (xlwings)

Tags: xlwings

I am trying to label the x and y axis of my chart, programmed in python using xlwings. API is needed and I want to label both the x and y axis. Below is my code, how can I label the x axis as "Cell #" and the y axis as "Cell Voltage"?

```
mainWorkbook.sheets.add('TP 5 - Final OCV', after=TP4sht)  # add test point averages sheet
TP5sht = mainWorkbook.sheets('TP 5 - Final OCV')  # variable name for sheet
TP5Chart = TP5sht.charts.add(left=160, top=20, width=700, height=400)
TP5Chart.set_source_data(TestPointAvgSheet.range((6, 67), (6, 76)))
TP5Chart.chart_type = 'column_clustered'
TP5Chart.api[1].FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = CellList
TP5Chart.name = "Final OCV"
TP5Chart.api[1].SetElement(2)  # Place chart title at the top
TP5Chart.api[1].ChartTitle.Text = 'TP 5 Final OCV CVs'  # Change text of the chart title
TP5Chart.api[1].Axes(1).HasTitle = True

# LABEL X AND Y AXIS??

TP5Chart.height = 250
TP5Chart.width = 250
TP5Chart.api[1].HasLegend = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines after `# LABEL X AND Y AXIS??` in your code:

```
TP5Chart.api[1].Axes(2).HasTitle = True # This line creates the Y axis label.
TP5Chart.api[1].Axes(1).AxisTitle.Text = "x axis text" 
TP5Chart.api[1].Axes(2).AxisTitle.Text = "y axis text"
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.axes#example) is a VBA example.

Answer (score 0):

I think an error will appear, because you only have the value of xlValue but you are missing the xlPrimary, for it to work properly it should look like this:

```
xlvalue=1
ylvalue=2
xlprimary=1
TP5Chart.api[1].Axes(xlvalue,xlprimary).HasTitle = True # This line creates the Y axis label.
TP5Chart.api[1].Axes(xlvalue,xlprimary).AxisTitle.Text = "x axis text"

TP5Chart.api[1].Axes(ylvalue,xlprimary).HasTitle = True # This line  
TP5Chart.api[1].Axes(ylvalue,xlprimary).AxisTitle.Text = "y axis text"
```

Note the **additional parameter xlprimary in Axes**